# Getting wrong answer for absolute value inequality and not sure why

Tags: absolute-value

The question:

**The function p is defined by $-2|x+4|+10$. Solve the equality $p(x) > -4$**

Here were my steps to solving this:

1.) *Subtract 10 from both sides* -> $-2|x+4| > -14$

2.) *Divide both sides by -2* -> $|x+4|>7$

3.) $x+4$ should therefore be 7 units or greater from zero on the number line, meaning either greater than 7 or less than -7:

$x+4 > 7$

$x+4 < -7$

4.) *Subtract 4 from both sides:*

$x > 3$

$x < -11$

Graphing this, I see my signs are the wrong way round but I'm not quite sure where I've gone wrong.

Comment: When you divide by a negative number, the sign needs to reverse as well.

Comment: I did reverse it. -14 became 7

Comment: Sorry. I meant the inequality sign goes from > to <.

Comment: You didn’t reverse the inequality sign.

Comment: I see! Thanks very much.

Comment: A little tip: when you know the answer is wrong, you can find faulty steps by substituting a bad value into the previous steps. You know that the answer shouldn't include $x > 3$ as your working shows, so try substituting $x = 4$ into each step. Initially, you get a false inequality, but at the first step of bad working, it magically becomes true!

Comment: @TheoBendit Great tip thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

$20$ is greater than $8$, right?

$$20 > 8$$

Now divide both sides by $-2$:

$$-10 > -4$$

Whoops! That's not right. This is because when you multiply or divide an inequality by a negative number, you must change the sense of the inequality: $>$ becomes $<$, and $\le$ becomes $\ge$ etc:

$$-10 < -4$$

Comment: The glorious feeling of catharsis! Thanks Tony, I'll accept your answer in 7 minutes :)

Comment: Can't help but think the example would have been clear with `divide by -1` but good answer

Answer (score 9):

$-2|x+4|>-14$ implies that $|x+4|<7$ (the greater than becomes smaller than because you multiply by a negative number).

The rest is all good.

Comment: Did you lose your 2 somewhere in there? Or in fact gain an unwanted 2 I think...

Comment: He meant $-14$ in the first inequality.